# calling .trigger on javascript createElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, csrf, csrf-protection

I am implementing a CSRF solution that automatically injects a token stored on the session into all forms before subitting them. I have implemented 2 solutions to ensure all submissions are handled

1. For ajax submissions I have implemented a jquery.ajaxPreFilter method that adds the token to the data attributes before passing it through to the ajax handler.
2. For other forms, I bind to the submit event using jquery.on('submit').
3. For forms being submitted via javascript I have changed my .submit() calls to .trigger('submit');

There are some javascript methods in our code that will use javascript document.createElement() to create a form, before calling form.submit(). I am unable to change these to form.trigger('submit') as jquery does not recognise them; I get  error "form.trigger is not a function".

How can I handle these types of form submissions to trigger the submit event so that my binding method will pick it up?

Comment: This would be easier to respond to if you included all relevant code. However, the problem may simply be that `createElement()` returns a plain DOM element, not a jQuery collection where the `.trigger()` function is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found a solution, and didn't realise it was so simple.

Instead of calling

```
form.submit();
```

I just call

```
$(form).trigger('submit');
```